# WinUI 3 Frame not Binding

Tags: mvvm, winui-3

- WinUI 3 Desktop App (WindowsApp 1.2.230313.1)
- C# MVPVM Code Pattern

I have created a problem with binding my View's Frame with the ViewModel's Frame encapsulating property. What is happening (without any errors or application crash), is when I select a NavigationView's Item (NavigationViewItem), it executes fine, and binds to the ViewModel accordingly. The View's Frame UIElement does not respond to the changes. Am I binding to the wrong property?

My View:

```
<NavigationView MenuItemsSource="{x:Bind p.ViewModel.GetNavigationViews}"
                    ItemInvoked="{x:Bind p.ViewModel.ItemInvoked}">
        <NavigationView.Content>
            <ScrollViewer>
                <Frame DataContext="{x:Bind p.ViewModel.ContentFrame}"/>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </NavigationView.Content>
    </NavigationView>
```

My ViewModel:

```
public Frame ContentFrame { get; set; } = new();
```

My Presenter:

```
 public class MainPagePresenter : PagePresenterBase<MainPageView, MainPageViewModel>
{
    public MainPagePresenter() : base()
    {
        ViewModel.ItemInvoked = new(ItemInvoked);
    }

    void ItemInvoked(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)
    {
        FrameNavigationOptions options = new()
        {
            TransitionInfoOverride = args.RecommendedNavigationTransitionInfo
        };
        if (sender.PaneDisplayMode == NavigationViewPaneDisplayMode.Auto)
        {
            options.IsNavigationStackEnabled = false;
        }

        Type pageType = null;

        switch (args.InvokedItem)
        {
            case "Subscriptions": pageType = typeof(SubscriptionsView); break;
            case "Account Link": pageType = typeof(AccountLinkView); break;         
        }
        ViewModel.ContentFrame.NavigateToType(pageType, null, options);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `DataContext` is something like setting data in the background for bindings.
So, in your case, you need to set ContentFrame as `ScrollViewer`'s `Content`.

```xml
<NavigationView
    ItemInvoked="{x:Bind p.ViewModel.ItemInvoked}"
    MenuItemsSource="{x:Bind p.ViewModel.GetNavigationViews}">
    <NavigationView.Content>
        <ScrollViewer Content="{x:Bind p.ViewModel.ContentFrame, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </NavigationView.Content>
</NavigationView>
```

Comment: OK that worked. But gave me more unknown errors for no reason. Thanks @Andrew KeepCoding

Comment: Ok this works. but I'm guessing this solution is crashing my app. it just closes the app.

Comment: I actually created a sample app and it works (navigates). What kind of errors you get? Can you place breakpoints and debug it? If you remove the ''ScrollViewer'', does it still close the app?

Comment: It was working fine before needing the ScrollViewer. My page became too large that it needed a scrollviewer. It was also working fine before needing the x:Bind situation. Meaning I had it working in a 'code-behind' page, but wanted to move towards an MVPVM pattern like written above. So I'm not getting any errors with my coding or with managed coding. I think that's the proper term.

Comment: So since I could not find a point to debug, I thought I'd check the Event Viewer for anything to report, and I found this error:

Faulting application name: Management.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x63ed82c1
Faulting module name: Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll, version: 3.0.0.2303, time stamp: 0x6c39c3fc
Exception code: 0xc000027b
Fault offset: 0x00000000007cd8bc
Faulting process id: 0x0x1214
Faulting application start time: 0x0x1D969B49A5F7A2C

Comment: Never saw that message. Can you post a new question with [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Out of process of emlination, I think my problem is not relatable to this topic.